# Cookie without SameSite Attribute

Tags: security, web

When I scanned a Particular web app using ZAP it displays mentioning the site has "Cookie without SameSite Attribute" I read that we can perform CSRF attack for this vulnerability. Can anyone explain to me how to do that?.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for instructions on how to exploit a vulnerability. Perhaps you could rephrase this to explain the problem you are looking to fix?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF attacks are done by providing a link with hidden parameters to a victim and hoping that he is activating that link while he has a still active session in his browser for the destination web page at the same time. 
It can lead to actions that the user didn't intend.

Cookies that use the sameSite flag can reduce that risk, because the browser sends it only when certain conditions are given.

See simple examples at [Portswigger Academy](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf)

Note, that CSRF attacks are not legal. If you just want to learn about the topic, you have to try it with your own web page and your own cookies.

Comment: Thank you SiSi, I will try with my own website. But I still don't understand how to perform it practically.

Comment: See the HTML snipplet on Portswigger